# using microsoft's krabsetw utility to parse structured types in ETW

Tags: c++, winapi, etw

So I've been examining for a while microsoft's `krabsetw` example on how to handle and parse ETW events. Their example showed a simple usage regarding top level's fields, But what happens when arrays and complex structures are involved?

Simple usage : multiple_providers_001.cpp :

```
 krabs::parser parser(schema);
            auto url = parser.parse<std::string>(L"URL");
            auto request_headers = parser.parse<std::string>(L"RequestHeaders");
            auto response_headers = parser.parse<std::string>(L"ResponseHeaders");
            std::cout << "\tURL: " << url << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\t\tRequest Headers: " << request_headers << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\t\tResponse Headers: " << response_headers << std::endl;
```

Interface's deceleration:

```
template <typename T>
bool try_parse(const std::wstring &name, T &out);

/**
 * <summary>
 * Attempts to parse the given property by name and type. If the
 * property does not exist, an exception is thrown.
 * </summary>
 */
template <typename T>
T parse(const std::wstring &name);

template <typename Adapter>
auto view_of(const std::wstring &name, Adapter &adapter) -> collection_view<typename Adapter::const_iterator>;
```

So to summarize, In cases where i would be asked to provide the following's value: `A\B\C\Struct\Array`, such operation even plausible with their API? or should i convert everything into JSON and friends and extract it from there?